# loading 3rdparty plugins with a specified order using requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

In my web application, I am using requirejs 2.1.9. We all know that order is removed from the latest version of requirejs.

Now, I have a bunch of plugins to be loaded and some them are interdependent. I can use shim config to define dependencies among them and all plugins can be downloaded at once and will be initialized based on the dependency I have defined in shim config.

My problem is that, I dont want to load all the plugins at once. When I navigate to a webpage, only a part of the plugins are needed. I would want to download remaining whenever they are needed.

An example scenario:
I have modules A B C D E F G.
F is dependent on G.

Now, When I am in page 1, lets say I have downloaded plugins A, C, F. I dont want to download G along with F. Since F is dependedent on G, F will not work properly. Since Shim can only be configured once per application launch, I cant use it here.

How can I solve this? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out a library I have written: [require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/require-lazy)

It does what you want automatically (check the [shim example](https://github.com/nikospara/require-lazy/tree/master/examples/shim)) and integrates with r.js